# Cannot add requirejs-text plugin in brunch-with-marionette application

Tags: requirejs, marionette, brunch, requirejs-text

I used brunch-with-marionette skeleton available at: https://github.com/SimbCo/brunch-with-marionette Everything works fine for me but I don't know the necessary configuration in this skeleton to add requirejs-text plugin. I tried:

```
npm install requirejs-text
```

and it installed the plugin in node-modules folder but then when I tried to load a template like this:

```
items = require 'text!views/sub-menu/templates/panel'
```

the browser gives error about being unable to load file 'text!views/....'. It considers the whole thing a file name. Removing the "text!" part works but then it doesn't return the html text rather, it gives a function which is not what I need.

I even checked the installed plugin with "npm ls" command from the app folder but when it lists the node-modules, it says the following for requirejs-text:

```
npm ERR! extraneous: requirejs-text@2.0.12
```

I am working on this stuff for the first time. Kindly help me with the configuration to add requirejs-text plugin. Many thanks!

EDITED:

I am using coffeescript. Adding some code from search-menu-view.coffee file for reference:

```
SubMenuView = require 'views/sub-menu/sub-menu-view'
favorites = require 'models/favorites'
navTemplate = require 'text!views/sub-menu/templates/menu-panel'

module.exports = class SearchMenuView extends SubMenuView
    template: 'views/sub-menu/templates/menu-search'
    events:
        'click .menu-search-btn-group': 'onSearchInputClick'
```

The first two files load fine. The third one which has `text!` in it, doesn't.

Comment: @Louis Actually I didn't have to configure RequireJS. I downloaded the skeleton code from [link](https://github.com/SimbCo/brunch-with-marionette) and it had everything configured and worked for me. I don't know the configurations yet but the skeleton code contain files like: bower.json ; config.coffee ; package.json and they all have some kind of configurations. I have edited the question to include the context of require call you asked.

Comment: It looks like your `require 'text!...` call is processed as a CommonJS call and that it is not processed by RequireJS. (RequireJS does accept a CommonJS form of the `require` call but it does not produce the error you got.) That's about as much as I can tell because from what I can see Brunch is what should take care of your `require` calls but I've never used it.